# How to set order of classes with tests

Tags: junit5

I have several classes with integration tests and I need to set order, in which will be these classes proceed.

I use junit5 in version 5.4.1.

Please advice possible solutions.

Comment: You can define the order of methods within the class itself but enforcing the order on classes just seems like a design flaw. They should be independent / isolated units of work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control the order in which test classes are executed in JUnit Jupiter.

JUnit Jupiter only provides a mechanism for controlling the execution order of methods within a single test class.

See [Test Execution Order](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order) in the User Guide for details.